# C++ - Passing rapidjson::Document as an argument to a function

Tags: c++, json, arguments, rapidjson

I'm passing pointer to `rapidjson::Document` as an argument.

```
foo(rapidjson::Document* jsonDocument)
{
    std::cout << jsonDocument["name"] << std::endl;
}
```

But I cannot do `jsonDocument["name"]` to access the name attribute.

Attempting to not use pointers leads to an error:

```
error: 'rapidjson::GenericDocument<Encoding, Allocator, StackAllocator>::GenericDocument(const rapidjson::GenericDocument<Encoding, Allocator, StackAllocator>&) [with Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>; StackAllocator = rapidjson::CrtAllocator]' is private
GenericDocument(const GenericDocument&);
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can't find the dupe, but there are many. In short you need to dereference the pointer before using it like `(*jsonDocument)["name"]` or `jsonDocument[0]["name"]` or use a reference such as `rapidjson::Document& jsonDocument`.

Comment: Using a reference is the best solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a reference or a value as argument. Using the `[]` with a pointer will try to use your document as if it was an array of document. A reference or a value will call the expected operator.

```
// a const reference
foo(const rapidjson::Document& jsonDocument) {
    std::cout << jsonDocument["name"] << std::endl;
}

// a copy (or move)
foo(rapidjson::Document jsonDocument) {
    std::cout << jsonDocument["name"] << std::endl;
}
```

I'd recommend you to use the reference, as your function don't need to consume any resources in the document, but only observe and print a value.

The call of this function will look like this:

```
rapidjson::Document doc = /* ... */;

foo(doc);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm using a const reference.

Comment: Could you add how you can save a Value in a local variable if you pass the Document as const reference? Here an example `foo(const rapidjson::Document &d){ const Value &v = d["name"]; }`

Comment: @i7clock do you mean a copy? If yes, then `auto doc_copy = doc!` should be sufficient.

Comment: I mean for further extracting values and manipulating the DOM, but thanks for showing me how to do a copy